# How do I paste into the "crosh" terminal in a Chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> while having Chrome open to open a terminal in my Chromebook. How do I paste content into this terminal copied from another tab in Chrome?

I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to no avail. I have also tried highlighting text and pasting it via the middle button on my mouse, which failed too.

I have also read this article (http://www.servercobra.com/nothing-but-chromebook-for-a-week/) and tried triple clicking my touch pad, but it isn't working for me.

Comment: shift insert maybe? The middle mouse botton trick is for X, and i don't seem to think that chromeos uses x

Comment: Here is how the keyboard for Chromebooks looks like: http://apcmag.com/images/2011/chromebook-keyboard.jpg Where is the ins key?

Comment: My bad there. Hence is being a comment, and not an answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the knowledge though. I did not know that you can paste with those keys in Linux.

Comment: Pressing Ctrl-Alt-/ will bring up a keyboard map where you can hold down Ctrl, Shift, Alt, Search and combinations of those buttons to find the key combinations for keys not on the keyboard. On my Asus C300, Search-. (period) generates an "Insert" keystroke.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> works for me in crosh. Chrome OS Version 21.0.1180.83.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried crosh, but maybe it is <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd>, like in a linux terminal.

Comment: Thanks, what do you think of my comment above?

Answer (score 1):

Doing a two finger click, aka right click, works too.

Right click is a common way of pasting on many *nix systems.

Comment: nd it's the middle button, not the right button, that's the common way of pasting on Unix systems. Anyway, oddly enough, tapping the pad with two fingers did not work for me, but pressing the pad with two fingers (which produces an audible and tactile "click") did.

Comment: You're right, it's the middle button on most *nix systems. It's been ages since I've last used a 3 button mouse.  As for the tap vs click, it might be a configuration issue - I'm using non-default configuration on Samsung Chromebook - YMMV

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate Ctrl + Insert on a Chromebook you can press the

`Ctrl + search key + period key (.)`

at the same time. The search key is located above the shift key on the left. Shift + Insert can be done via

`Shift + search key + period key`

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and bookmark it then you can probably move the bookmark onto a separate page.